# Binding a function as a method that receives `self` in a position other than first

Tags: python, methods

I have the following situation:

```
# Module A.py

def AddThreeNumbers(a, b, c, parent=None):
    """
    Add `a + b + c` and return the result.

    If `parent` is supplied, additionally store
    the result in `parent.result`.

    `parent` is optional, so we don't want it
    to be the first argument when this is
    called as a global function.
    """

    result = a + b + c
    if parent:
        parent.result = result
    return result
```

and:

```
# Module B.py

class SomeClass:
    # ... various methods
    pass

try:
    import A
except ImportError:
    # The `A` module may or may not be available.
    pass # If it isn't, no harm no foul, but...
else:
    # if module `A` *is* available, then we would
    # like to monkey-patch the `SomeClass` class
    # so that it has an `AddThreeNumbers` method...

    SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers = XXX( A.AddThreeNumbers )
```

The `XXX` on the last line is the missing piece. I want
to **somehow** transform the `AddThreeNumbers` function
so that `self` will get passed in as the last argument
(`parent`) rather than the first.   I could of course
wrap it:

```
SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers = lambda self, a, b, c: A.AddThreeNumbers(a, b, c, parent=self)
```

...but that has two disadvantages. First, I lose the `__doc__` (I suppose that could be worked around with `functools.wraps`) and second I have to maintain the signature (argument names `a`, `b` and `c`) in two places if that ever gets changed/extended.

Is there a better way?

Comment: What should happen if `A` is not available and somebody calls `SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers`?

Comment: @BlackBear in reality, that calls a stub that raises an exception with an understandable and actionable message, "you need to install the `A` module"

Comment: I would agree with that first answer unless there's a good reason to work around some issue that is out of your control. In that case, that link may be useful: https://chriswarrick.com/blog/2018/09/20/python-hackery-merging-signatures-of-two-python-functions/
It is pretty hacky and ugly if you're only doing that for that one function IMO, so may not be worth it. But if you need to do that for several methods in that library, might be worth checking.

Comment: @jadkik94  Thanks, the `merge_args` package has exactly the sort of information I was looking for—not because I necessarily think I should use it or its approach, but because it gives a good analysis of what can/cannot be done, and what it takes.

Comment: @jez Yeah that's why I posted this as a comment, because it looks way overkill for what you're trying to achieve, but the approach is explained in the blog post so it might guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @jadkik94  I think that's actually the closest it gets to a definitive answer, so I've posted it below.  I agree that it may not be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wrapper could just take `(self, *args, **kwargs)` so you don't need to duplicate things. And as you mentioned, `functools.wraps` is always a good idea for wrappers.

However this seems a bit smelly to me. `AddThreeNumbers` should only care about adding three numbers; setting that result on another object should be someone else's responsibility. Maybe the wrapper should do it:

```
@functools.wraps(A.AddThreeNumbers)
def add_three_numbers_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.result = A.AddThreeNumbers(*args, **kwargs)
    return self.result

SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers = add_three_numbers_wrapper
```

Comment: Thanks—I had considered using `*args, **kwargs` and I guess it might be the best way, but its residual problem with that is that it destroys the signature of the function for introspection/help purposes.   As for the smell, there are reasons/excuses in the real context. (It's all about convenience:  `parent` actually bundles together a lot of information that can be *used* in the function, and that info otherwise has to be passed in laboriously argument by argument—however, this *can* at least be done if A is being used in the absence of B.)

Comment: My mistake, because for some reason I was testing in Python 2.   Under Python 3, this actually works perfectly, including adjusting the signature for purposes of `help()` and IPython tab-completion.

Comment: However you need to correct `@functools.wraps`  to `@functools.wraps(A.AddThreeNumbers)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @jadkik94 for the pointer to the blog post that links to [merge_args](https://pypi.org/project/merge_args) and [makefun](https://pypi.org/project/makefun), both third-party packages that seem to be able to do this.

Here's an example that works (Python 3+ only):

```
from merge_args import merge_args
@merge_args(A.AddThreeNumbers)
def AddThreeNumbers( self, *pargs, **kwargs ):
    kwargs[ 'parent' ] = self
    return A.AddThreeNumbers( *pargs, **kwargs )
SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers = AddThreeNumbers
```

The `help()` output looks perfect. So it's just a question of whether it's worth adding the dependency on `merge_args` (or copying the 100+ lines of "Advanced Hackery" that it contains).

Update:  I later found that under Python 3 (or at least 3.7), `functools.wraps` achieves *almost* the same thing:

```
import functools
@functools.wraps(A.AddThreeNumbers)
def AddThreeNumbers( self, *pargs, **kwargs ):
    kwargs[ 'parent' ] = self
    return A.AddThreeNumbers( *pargs, **kwargs )
SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers = AddThreeNumbers
```

...except that `self` is missing from the signature in the output of `help(B.SomeClass.AddThreeNumbers)` and the first argument is swallowed (because it is assumed to play the role of `self`) in the output of `help(B.SomeClass().AddThreeNumbers)`.